# PowerShell Install Module command not failing but not installing module

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, powershellget

I am trying to install the PnP online commands for SharePoint onto my PowerShell however the following command doesn't seem to work;

```
Install-Module -name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -scope CurrentUser
```

The command seems to run through fine with no errors appearing but when I try to run Commands which should have been installed I get an error saying the commands can not be found.

```
connect-pnponline : The term 'connect-pnponline' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of        
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ connect-pnponline
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (connect-pnponline:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have had a look at all the module folders and the module is not in any of them. I have compared my environment paths with a coworker who has this working and they are the same.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Try adding the -verbose parameter to see if that gives you any clues, at the very least it should list out the available commands. It could be that your version of the module doesn't contain the command you are trying.

Comment: What does `Get-Module "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline" -ListAvailable` show you?

Comment: You tried importing the module after you installed it? e.g Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by by modules being stored on OneDrive. By default my module path was set to "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" but since i had OneDrive installed my path changed to "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules".

To resolve this issue I went to Documents>Windows Powershell>Modules and copied the link. Then, via the Start' menu, I went to 'Edit the system environment variables'>advanced>Environment Variables, highlighted PSModulePath and clicked Edit.
Once in this window I clicked New and pasted the link I found above.
This resolved the problem I was experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

The module probably isn't imported. You should be able to execute
`Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` which should either import your module, or give you an error if it can't be imported for some reason.

To tackle the non-autoloading issue, check the following:

- Check that you're setting [`$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmoduleautoloadingpreference?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and that it's not set to `None` or `0`
- [Cmdlets which make use of a PowerShell provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-5.1#module-auto-loading) do not get automatically imported

  - [`SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) implements a SharePoint provider so I'd wager this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom `The term '' is not recognized...`, but a different fix.

When I checked `$ENV:PSModulePath` in Windows Powershell (this problem was not present in `pwsh` powershell core), I saw the expected folder `C:\Users\cwalsh\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` was missing:

Instead `$ENV:PSModulePath` was `;;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`

The root cause was I had `PSModulePath` env var defined at **both** User-level as `;` (this is *not* how my other PC is set up), and at System-level as `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`. I guess unlike `PATH` this variable doesn't automatically concatenate both.

I deleted the user-level `PSModulePath` environment variable and now in a new process the module works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Onedrive syncing screwed up the files for MgGraph authentication.
one of the subfolders sync was broken he file was removed because "cloud" didnt know about it. Had to reinstall... Need to change the default location out of documents if you have onedrive so silly

Comment: This answer is based on a personal experience that is too local to make it comprehensible as a generic answer. Also, how does this add anything to the already sufficient answers?