# "Connect-MsGraph' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a couple of PowerShell scripts that can run using Windows PowerShell with no issue.

As soon as I run them in VS Code on the same computer, I get "Connect-MsGraph' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

I have installed the same Microsoft.Graph.Intune and other relevant AAD modules for both Windows PowerShell and VS Code.

Any idea why I can't run them in the VS Code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Connect-MsGraph' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

The issue happens because of the VS code is not able to access the `PSModulePath` in the system or it happens if you are not using the latest `Microsoft.Graph` SDK.

Try to install the module in a default path

```
    Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph -RequiredVersion 1.2.0
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64277495/15997690) if in your system default path contains OneDrive.

After adding the required modules in a default path try to restart the VS Code and System.

#### References

- [Connect MS Graph in VS Code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/243)

Comment: Hi DelliganeshS-MT,

Thanks for the suggestion.

I checked my system variables. I have the %Programs%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules as default PSModulePath. I checked the folder and can also confirm modules are actually there.

I also have OneDrive so I added my OneDrive Path too.

I also tried the Install-Module cmd with required version, still getting the same error so far.

One thing to mention is I am a standard user and not running VS Code as local admin.

Comment: We can able to run the PowerShell script in VS code. Can you try to reinstall the VS code once.